# How to access JSON value in C# from a JArray?

Tags: c#, json

I have have the following JSON data that i'm retrieving from a database. How do I go about getting the value of the label property?

```
{
    elementAttributes: {
    "layout": "row"
    },
    fieldGroup: [
    {
        type: "select",
        key: "title",
        className: "flex-100 layout-column",
        templateOptions: {
        label: "Title *",
        multiple: false,
        required: true,
        disabled: false,
        labelProp: "desc",
        valueProp: "id",
        options: [
            { desc: "Mr", id: 1 },
            { desc: "Mrs", id: 2 },
            { desc: "Ms", id: 3 },
            { desc: "Miss", id: 4 },
            { desc: "Dr", id: 5 }
        ],
        description: ""                          
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use **Newtonsoft.Json**, there is very good example:

> http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm

To generate class, u can use:

> http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this as the JSON object is dynamic

Comment: So use JObject.Prase(string);